# How to create a docker container out of existing project on Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, digital-ocean

I have a Django project being hosted on Digital Ocean that I'm trying to migrate to AWS.  My project is currently not setup at all with portability in mind.  I'm wondering if a clean solution would just be to create a docker container and move that to AWS?

My question is (assuming Docker is already setup), how to I create a container with my project in it?

Do I just create a container and my project is already in the container?  Or do I have to move all my files into the new container?

I ask because the tutorials online make it unclear to me how to do this.

Comment: Yes, you can do `docker pull django` to get the official image of Django and run a container and copy your project into it using `docker cp` command.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if a clean solution would just be to create a docker container and move that to AWS?

Not really. AWS and Digital Ocean both give you shell access to a virtual Linux machine. Migrating to Docker will take as much work as migrating to AWS, plus you'll need to spend some time learning about Docker.

If you have a single Django project (not lots of little services) and you just want to move to AWS (not jump around between multiple providers), then I recommend not introducing Docker. It's a fun technology, but I don't see how it's going to benefit you here.